# Qt C++ use method of creating class in created objects

Tags: c++, qt, class

I`m still stuck.

I have a GUI-class that creates an Object. From a method of this new Object I want to use methods of the creating class

I have a Gui(PBV)  with line_Edits and a Combobox. In this Combobox I can choose between different Geometries. Geo_1, Geo_2,… that inherit from Geometry. According to the entries in the combobox I want to create different Objects (Geo_1,Geo_2,…) that then set the lineEdits of the creating class according to the needs of the Geo_n-Object.

**I don`want to do that with signal-slot**

I asked different questions on that but I can`t get further.

**I somehow feel this is kind of recursive... Is there a solution fort hat?**

Here is my code:

PBV.h:

```
#include "../Geometry/Geo_1.h"

 class PBV : public Tab
 {
     Q_OBJECT    
 public:
     explicit PBV (QWidget *parent = 0);
     ~ PBV ();
     virtual void printContent( QStringList *const qsl);

private:    
    Geo_1 *GEO_1;
    Geometry *GEO;
 }
```

PBV.cpp:

```
 …
 Geo_1 *GEO_1;
 GEO_1 = new Geo_1(this);
 GEO_1->set_LNE_default();
 …
```

.

```
Geo_1.h:
#ifndef GEO_1_H
#define GEO_1_H 
#include "Geometry.h"
#include "../Tabs/PBV.h"
class Geo_1: public Geometry
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
    Geo_1 (QObject *_parent = 0);
    virtual void set_LNE_default();
};  
#endif // GEO_1_H
```

.

```
Geo_1.cpp:
#include "Geometry.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include "Geo_1.h"
#include "../Tabs/PBV.h"

Geo_1::Geo_1(QObject*_parent)
: Geometry(_parent) {}

void Geo_1::set_LNE_default()
{
    // here I want to use printContent  
}
```

.

```
Geometry.h:

 #ifndef GEOMETRY_H
 #define GEOMETRY_H
 #include <QObject>

 class Geometry : public QObject
 {
     Q_OBJECT
 public:
     Geometry(QObject *_parent=0);
     ~Geometry();
     virtual void set_LNE_default();
 };
 #endif // GEOMETRY_H
```

.

```
Geometry.cpp:

 #include "Geometry.h"
 #include <QDebug>

 Geometry::Geometry(QObject *_parent)
     : QObject(_parent)     {}

 Geometry::~Geometry(){}
 void Geometry::set_LNE_default() { }
```

Answer (score 3):

When PBV allocates a Geo_1 instance, it is **already** passing a **pointer to itself in the constructor**:

```
GEO_1 = new Geo_1(this); // "this" is your PBV instance
```

Why not save the pointer to use later?

```
Geo_1::Geo_1(PBV*_parent) : Geometry((QObject*)_parent)
{
    this->pbv = _parent; // Save reference to parent
}
```

Then you can do:

```
void Geo_1::set_LNE_default()
{
    // here I want to use printContent
    this->pbv->printContent(...); // this->pbv is your saved ptr to the PBV that created this instance
}
```

**EDIT**

Additonally, you might run into the problem that you will have to cross-include the two headers (PBV and Geo_1), to fix this, remove the include for Geo_1 from PBV.h and [forward-declare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c) Geo_1. Just like this:

```
class Geo_1;
```

Before declaring your PBV class.

Comment: this does not work. When I declare in PBV.h a Geo:1 *GEO_1 he shows me that in correct colours(purple &red) indicating that he knows Geo_1. This is OK since I did  #include "../Geometry/Geo_1.h" on top of PbV.h  But still I get the error: Geo_1 does not name a type, prototype for Geo_1::Geo_1(PBV*) does not match any in class Geo_1.  WHY ???????    I have the impression It has something to do with my #includes